# WKWebView not resizing in fullscreen when added in SwiftUI with NSScrollView

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, wkwebview, appkit

Adding a custom `NSScrollView` into `SwiftUI`, there is a `WKWebview` inside a `HStack` which is added to `NSScrollView` via `NSHostingView`

The `WKWebview` doesn't go fullscreen properly (doesnt resize and sticks to the leading
edge) when
`child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, if I skip this then the
fullscreen works as normal however the `AutoLayout` won't work because of this.

```swift
     struct ContentView: View {
      var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewX {
                HStack {
   
                    WebViewX()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
           
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 500, height : 500)
            
        }.frame(width: 700, height : 700)
    }
    }



    struct ScrollViewX<Content : View>: NSViewRepresentable {
    let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustomScrollView {
        let view = CustomScrollView(frame: .zero)
        let child = NSHostingView(rootView: content)
        child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.documentView = child
       child.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
       child.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: CustomScrollView, context: Context) {
    }
     }

     class CustomScrollView: NSScrollView {
    
     override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.drawsBackground = false
        self.hasHorizontalScroller = true
        self.hasVerticalScroller = false
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

    }

     struct WebViewX: NSViewRepresentable {

    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> customWebView {
        let webView = customWebView(url: nil)
        return webView
    }
        
    func updateNSView(_ NSView: customWebView, context: Context) {
    }
     }

    class customWebView : WKWebView {
    convenience init(url : String?) {
        

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        
        config.limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains = false
        config.preferences.isTextInteractionEnabled = true
        config.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "fullScreenEnabled")
        config.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        self.init(frame: .zero, configuration : config)

        self.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
        self.allowsMagnification = true
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")!)
        
        self.load(req)

    }
    
    convenience required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
     }
```

Comment: Not really sure what are you going to achieve here? WKWebView on macOS has own internal NSScrollView, so just put it in view hierarchy and load URLs. Thus, what is that all code for?

Comment: @Asperi it's a simplified version of code from a bigger app which requires this type of behaviour.

Comment: Confused by your code, but I had a very similar issue with the SwiftUI VideoPlayer and it was to do with the SafeAreas. Once I told the player to ignore the safe areas, it would play in full screen. Pretty sure its a bug, but yeah, removing safe areas worked for me. ☺️

Comment: @JamesWilliam I solved this, it's happening due to the fixed frame. I tried ignoring safe areas but that's not helping.

Answer (score 1):

All conditions still not clear, but actually it is horizontal scroller, so height definitely can be constraint, but for content... every view have to have some width defined (or at least have some rule to calculate). Any other  hardcodes should be removed.

Thus with below changes all works in full screen as expected automatically (tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4)

[image: demo]

```
// in main: 

        VStack {
            ScrollViewX {
                HStack {
                    WebViewX(url: "https://www.apple.com")
                        .frame(width: 500)
                    WebViewX(url: "https://www.google.com")
                        .frame(width: 500)
                    WebViewX(url: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")
                        .frame(width: 500)
                    WebViewX()
                        .frame(width: 500)
                }
            }
        }
    }

// in ScrollViewX:

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustomScrollView {
        let view = CustomScrollView(frame: .zero)
        let child = NSHostingView(rootView: content)
        child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.documentView = child
        child.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        child.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        // this one !!
        child.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        return view
    }
```

[Complete test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_macOS/PlayOn_macOS/Findings/TestMultiWebViewScroller.swift)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it thanks to @Asperi

The issue is due to the frame() on WebViewX()

When you add a NSHostingView() in Appkit the SwiftUI frame modifier disables the view from resizing during fullscreen.

The solution is to change the frame() on willEnterFullscreen and exitFullscreen notifications.

Maybe there are better solutions using Auto-layout